# Display a spinner as img src attribute is set using FileReader()

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the following code to read a image file and set the result as the src for an image attribute,

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("upload-image"),
    function(fileElement) {
        var previewElement = document.createElement("img");
        previewElement.style.display = "block";
        fileElement.parentNode.insertBefore(previewElement, fileElement);

        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function(event) {
            previewElement.src = event.target.result;
        };

        fileElement.addEventListener("change", updateImagePreview, false);
        updateImagePreview();

        function updateImagePreview() {
            var file = fileElement.files[0];
            if (file) {
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                var placeholderSrc = fileElement.getAttribute("data-placeholder");
                if (placeholderSrc) {
                    previewElement.src = placeholderSrc;
                } else {
                    previewElement.removeAttribute("src");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This works well, however I know that it takes some time for the actual image src to be set and for the image to be displayed.

Is there anyway for me to detect when the image src is set, and loaded, and ready to be displayed?

Comment: You mean despite `onload`?

Comment: I mean I'd not thought to use onload, thanks.